# PB won't accept SQL ORDER BY statement

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a nesetd SQL qry that works SSMS 2008 and in PB version 11.2.  When I add an ORDER BY statement in SSMS ist works, when I add the ORDER BY statement in PB I get the following error:

Select Error: SQLSTATE = 37000
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

any ideas why this happening and how I can resolve it?

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: Posting the specific syntax may help (I've used ORDER BY plenty of times with no problems), but I'd also try it in a native SQL Server tool to see if the syntax passes there.

Comment: Terry is correct, use the native driver and you'll be fine.  The curly braces are from the odbc driver and the TSQL instance doesn't seem to allow them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is definitely a Syntax error from the SQL engine, I’d suggest you use SQL Profiler to trace the SQL to determine where the problem is and go from there.